# External print.css file - How to make element visible on print only, not visible on screen?

Tags: css, print-css

I am currently using the following as my external print.css file:

> /* Remove unwanted elements */
>
> ## hiddenedit, #hiddenbuttons, #header, #nav, .propertyselector, li.hiddentab,  ul.hiddentab { display: none; }
>
> /* Ensure the content spans the full width */
>
> ## container, #container2, #content { width: 100%; margin: 0; float: none; }
>
> /* Change text colour to black (useful for light text on a dark
> background) */
> .lighttext { color: #000  }
>
> /* Improve colour contrast of links #781351 */
> a:link, a:visited {
> color: #000  }

I understand how this works to make display: none for the items that I do not want to print on the page.  My question is:  How can I do the reverse of this?  What would I do if there are elements on the page that I only want to be visible when the page prints, not visible when the page is viewed?

Any ideas?  Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply put

```
.onlyprint {display: none;}
@media print {
  .onlyprint {display: block;}
}
```

into your CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

Surely do exactly the reverse... in your screen css file set those items you want hidden to `display: none` and then get the print.css to show them.

Comment: what do you mean by "in my screen css file"?  do you mean the css in the page itself?

Answer (score 0):

You would have the online stylesheet say hidden, and the print css sheet say display. Is that what you mean? you would have to assign divs for it.

Comment: yes, i think this is what i want.  why is it necessary to use divs for it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer the following over phihag's code, because you can also apply it to other then block elements

```css
@media not print {
  .only-print {display: none!important;}
}
@media print {
  .only-not-print {display: none!important;}
}
```